# Facebook Messenger on website with different greeting message for each page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-messenger

I am just wondering if it is possible to set a different greeting message on messenger depending on the page you are on the website?

I know that we can have welcome message predefined when we set up for embed code on facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/ This was how it was set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosh! Overthinking again.. Didn't know it would be that easy. I was even trying to build a chat bot to achieve this. Logged in and out greeting message can be set as attributes when the chat is initialised!

```
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="YOUR_FB_PAGE_ID"
  theme_color="#2e3291"
  logged_in_greeting="Hello! We are here to answer any questions you may have."
  logged_out_greeting="Hello! We are here to answer any questions you may have.">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you know the messages and pages you want to display messages you could use a else if conditional control to display the message like:

```
 if (location.href == x.com) {
 // set message here
} else if (location.href == y.com) {
// set alternative here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wish it is that simple. I need to somehow push the custom message back into fb messenger, that's the part I can't find out.

Comment: Log the function as a const and assign the cost in fb messenger?